# Confusion about frame dependency of photon energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics, momentum, conservation-laws

Look at the picture below....My confusion is about frame dependence of photon energy...
Why cant we simply use the law of conservation of energy....according to which Mc²=energy of γ1+energy of γ2..by that Mc²=1+0.88=1.88..but that seems wrong..so what i m missing?

[image]

Comment: $M$ corresponds to the rest mass only. But the total energy conservation will also depend on the momentum, which you need to estimate from momentum conservation

Comment: Please say “to be” instead of “2 be”.

Comment: @KP99...sir help me solve this in rest frame of M...that what i m asking

Comment: you can work with the algebra of four vectors, that works in  all frames..You have the four vectors because you are given the angles in the laboratory system. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed method gives you the *energy* of the incoming particle in the lab frame;  it does not give you its *mass*.  To find the mass, you would also need to find the magnitude of the original particle's momentum, which will be the same as the total momentum of the two photons.

In the rest frame of the original particle, the photons would be emitted in opposite directions with equal energies.  If you knew what the photons' energies were in this frame, you could simply add up their energies to find the mass of the original particle (since the total momentum is zero in this frame.)  However, in the rest frame of the particle, neither of these photons would have the same energy as they do in the lab frame.  So you can't simply add the photon energies in the lab frame to get the total energy in the particle's rest frame.

Comment: sir...help me in understanding it in the rest frame of M

Comment: @SuhailSarwar:  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks sir...now u r on the track about what i had 2 ask u 4 help....So ur comment implies that photon energies are frame dependent....that is my problem....How could the energy of photon vary if its speed is same in all inertial frames...yes i know E=hν  ....so is it doppler shift that changes the energy of photon from 1 frame to another?

Comment: @SuhailSarwar:  Yes, you can think about the energy change in terms of the Doppler shift, or in terms of the Lorentz transformation of the photon's four-momentum (if you know what that is.)